# php как будет правильно проверить адрес сайта с www

Tags: php

гру php как будет правильно проверить адрес сайта с www или без
тоесть надо узнать используется ли www

Comment: удалите ваш ответ, т.к. он не является ответом. Все уточнения здесь пишут в комментариях.

Answer (score 0):

```
$params = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

if($params[0] == 'www') {
   // www exists   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

С отправкой заголовков и последующим редиректом, код выглядеть будет так:

```
<?php

if (substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, 3) == 'www') {
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header('Location: http://www.you-site.ru');
    die;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(preg_match('/^www/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) == 1) { }
```